# How do I translate a hash function from Python to R

Tags: python, r

I'm trying to translate the following python script to R, but I'm having difficulty that reflects that fact that I am not well versed with Python or R.

Here is what I have for Python:

```
import hashlib, hmac
print hmac.new('123456', 'hello'.encode('utf-8'),hashlib.sha256).digest()
```

When I run this in Python I'm getting a message that says standard output is empty.

Question:  What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I'm using for R

```
library('digest')
hmac('123456','hello', algo='sha256', serialize=FALSE)
```

My questions with the R code are:

1. How do I encode to utf-8 in R. I couldn't find a package.
2. What are the correct parameter settings for serialize and raw for R given I want to match the output of the Python function above (once its working).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the bytes of the hash in R, set `raw=TRUE`. Then you can write it out as a binary fine

```
library('digest')
x <- hmac('123456', enc2utf8('hello'), algo='sha256', serialize=FALSE, raw=TRUE)
writeBin(x, "Rout.txt")
```

If you're not outputting text, the encoding doesn't matter. These are raw bytes. The only different in the output is that the python print seems to be adding a new line character. If I hexdump on the R file i see

```
0000000 ac 28 d6 02 c7 67 42 4d 0c 80 9e de bf 73 82 8b
0000010 ed 5c e9 9c e1 55 6f 4d f8 e2 23 fa ee c6 0e dd
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to create a signing signature for amazon aws and I'm trying to follow this as an example: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html

Comment: So how does that make a difference?

Comment: I thought that might have barring on the encoding.  The example seems to take four different strings and builds to a final signature.  I believe the first three are Raw and the final is converted to hex.

Comment: I've added `enc2utf8()` to ensure the message string is encoded as utf-8.